# Why does the Gradle Copy task snapshot everything in the destination directory?

Tags: gradle, file-permissions

I've hit a problem with the [`Copy`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Copy.html) task, demonstrated by the following example:

```
task deploy(type: Copy) {
    from "foo.txt"
    into "/deployment"
}
```

where the content of `/deployment` is as follows:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 oliverc  oliverc    343 Feb 20 14:18 foo.txt
drwxr-x--- 22 oliverc  oliverc   4096 Feb 22 00:00 basic
drwxr-x---  9 root     root      4096 Jan 24 17:55 important
```

When I run `./gradlew deploy --stacktrace` (as the `oliverc` user), Gradle<sup>*</sup> complains:

```
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not list contents of directory '/deployment/important' as it is not readable.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.walkDir(DirectoryFileTree.java:141)
    at ... 
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileSnapshotter.java:44)
    at ...
```

Clearly, the complaint is correct (`/deployment/important` is owned by `root` and doesn't have world-readable permissions).  But it's apparent that Gradle's snapshot mechanism is trying to capture **everything** in the `into` target.  So:

1. Why should the `Copy` task care about irrelevant content in this directory?
2. Is there a Gradle-level workaround for this?<sup>**</sup>  (Let's assume that I'm stuck with these permissions and directory layout.)

---

<sub>* This was tested using Gradle 1.10.  I haven't investigated whether this is an issue with other versions.</sub>

** I realise I could use `Project.copy` instead of a `Copy` task, but then I lose incremental deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It snapshots everything in order to see if the task is up to date or not. If the sources and the target haven't changed since the last time the task was run, then Gradle optimizes it by not doing anything, and the task is marked as UP-TO-DATE.

My guess is that they don't try to be smart and determine exactly which files of the target directory must be snapshotted because the copy task also accepts `include` and  `rename` closures, and the task thus can't assume that nothing won't end up being copied to the `important` folder.

In general, Gradle works better (and assumes) that every target directory can be cleaned, and that a target directory isn't shared by two separate tasks.

I've not tested this workaround, but I would try defining my own task, using Project.copy(), and specifying its inputs and outputs explicitely and precisely, in order to not lose incremental deployment.

Comment: +1: you're right, this behaviour could be explained as the simplest way to cope with more complex copy specs.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known limitation of the `Copy` task, whose outputs are currently defined as an output directory. I don't think there is a solution that involves the `Copy` task; you can either use `Project.copy`, or implement your own copy task type that, say, defines its outputs as a set of files rather than a directory.

PS: `Copy` isn't really incremental; it either copies everything, or nothing.

Comment: Thanks!  A custom task seems to be in order here.  Re: "known limitation" - is the intention to enhance this behaviour in the future?  Re: "incremental" - I'm just echoing the wording in the docs: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html ;)

Comment: I think the intention is to improve the behavior at some point. Since you mentioned a need for "incremental deployment", I thought I should make clear that copying is all or nothing.